# Access members of linked list array passed to function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am using visual studio for C, where I am making an array of Nodes containing int datatypes (`startCount` and `endCount`) from a doubly linked list. So I am inserting the nodes from a d-linked list into this array. Then I am trying to sort it by partitioning it. 
And I get the following errors:

```
left of '->startCount' must point to struct union
expression must have pointer-to-class type
```

for the following code in the while statement:

```
int PartitionArray(DListNode*** sortArray){
........
while((*sortArray[left]->startCount - *sortArray[left]->endCount) < (pivot->startCount - pivot->endCount)){
left++;
}
........
}

where in main I have:
int main(){
DListNode **sortArray;
PartitionArray(sortArray);
}
```

I don't understand how I am suppose to access the values of the nodes through the array passed by reference.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you have defined your data structures, you may be dereferencing the variables the wrong way. As the * operator has a lower precedence, you may need to use

```
(*sortArray)[left]->startCount
```

or

```
(*sortArray[left])->startCount
```

or

```
(*sortArray)[left].startCount
```

or

```
(*sortArray[left]).startCount
```

instead of

```
*sortArray[left]->startCount
```

Comment: Thank you!
Now I have another question:
I am getting a segmentation fault when I set an element in sortArray to a pointer to a node inside the funciton:
int PartitionArray(DListNode*** sortArray){
DList Node = curNode;
sortArray[1] = curNode;
}

I get a segmentation fault.

Comment: It seems that sortArray may not have been initialized.

I would need to see the code before calling PartitionArray() to understand how the data structures are being handled.